# Creating a view to display records from more than two tables

Tags: sql, view, join

I need to create a view to display all the records from each of the employee dependent tables, and also it should show the join date of every employee as well from that particular employee's table. I used the following code, but it shows an error when I try to run it.

```
CREATE VIEW EmpDependent
AS
SELECT JoinDate
FROM Lecturer,BranchManager,NonAcademicStaff
INNER JOIN LecDependent.EmpRegNo=Lecturer.EmpRegNo=BranchManager.EmpRegNo=NonAcademicStaff.EmpRegNo
```

Please help

Comment: Does that `select` statement, when run by itself, return what you're looking for?

Comment: in from you have left    -- lecdepedent --

Comment: @Klaus: the error is most probably 'syntax error'; failing that, LecDependent is not listed in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 1):

Your join syntax is incorrect. Generally, to join two tables `A` and `B` you would have to do the following:

```
select a.*, b.* 
from A a inner join B b on b.a_id = a.id
```

Given that table `A` has a column called `id` and table `B` has a column named `a_id` (possibly and preferably being a foreign key).

You can add as many inner joins as like, for example you could extend the above with:

```
inner join C on c.b_id = b.id
```

Once you create a `select` statement that returns the rows you expect, you can create a view based on that statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like:

```
CREATE VIEW EmpDependent AS
    SELECT N.JoinDate
      FROM Lecturer         AS L
      JOIN BranchManager    AS B ON L.EmpRegNo = B.EmpRegNo
      JOIN NonAcademicStaff AS N ON B.EmpRegNo = N.EmpRegNo
```

However, your query lists a table LecDependent that is not cited in the FROM clause, and it is not clear why a lecturer is also a non-academic staff member and a branch manager (and maybe a lecturer is also their own dependent).

You also didn't give any indication of which table contains the JoinDate column - I guessed NonAcademicStaff, but it could be any of them.  And you'd be unlikely to need a 3 table join (or a 4 table join) for a single column without a number of filter conditions.

Overall, you need to think hard about the query you are encapsulating in the view.

Comment: actually each of the tables, Lecturer, BranchManager and NonAcademicStaff consists of the JoinDate column. and the dependent is also similar to that as, LecDependent, BrManDependent and NonAcDependent. So the output should be all the dependent details and the JoinDate as well

Comment: @Yoosuf: so what is the view supposed to show?  What are the outlines of each table?  I re-emphasize my last comment - 'you need to think hard about the query you are encapsulating'.  Actually, you need to have a good working query before you try encapsulating it in a view.

Comment: The view should show the JoinDate of each of the employees (lecturer, branchManager and NonAcademicStaff) as well as all of their respective dependent information

Comment: @Yoosuf: you need to show the outline schemas of the tables, indicate which columns are to be shown, and the keys of each table.  It sounds a bit as if you need a UNION view - one section of the UNION collects the lecturer (and lecturer's dependents) information; another collects the branch manager (and manager's dependents) information; and the third collects the information for non-academic staff and their dependents.  Fundamentally though, you should not even try creating a view until you have the basic query organized and working.